# Removing Dividers and Adding Space between Expandable List Groups Android

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-theme

I'm working on my theme in android and am having a heck of a time getting my Expandable List Views to look right. Here is my desired effect.

Collapsed
[image: Desired Collapsed List View]

Expanded
[image: Desired Expanded List View]

So I primarily want the space between each List Group. And since android also adds those dividers I want to get rid of all of them.

Here is what I'm getting without trying any trickery.

Collapsed
[image: Android Regular Collapsed]

Expanded
[image: Android Regular Expanded]

I assumed the best way to get my desired look would be to put a margin on the list group layout xml file but I get end up getting this. It does not put a spacer on my group indicator and also puts the space between the group and the child which I don't want.

Collapsed
[image: Attempted Fix Collapsed]

Expanded
[image: Attemped Fix Expanded]

Any help or a push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You can use these properties of listview dont know if it will solve your problem though:

```
android:divider="#FFF" // same as your background
android:dividerHeight="0dp"//for not showing one 
android:divider="@android:color/transparent" //setting divider to transparent
android:dividerHeight="-1dp"//setting negative height also works but only on relative and linear layout according to google engineers but I have tested it to work in many scenarios use this with care
```

Comment: setting the height to 0dp and the divider to transparent looks like it gets me half way there. Now I need to create a space between my list groups. How can that be done?

Comment: can you show us some code on your expandable listview this will enable us to provide you appropriate answer

Comment: @Dan You can set the divider as transparent and then set the height of the divider as you want. So that you can get the space as you expect.

Comment: so doing that way gives me the right look when the listview is collapsed. However when it's expanded it puts an unnecessary space here. http://i.imgur.com/K8YI59C.png